# Broken dependencies with apt

Tags: apt, dependencies

**I did a fresh install in the end**

I recently installed ubuntu and was trying to change my drivers from xserver to nvidia when I was first hit with the message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.9) but 2.4.8 is to be installed
 apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 2.4.8) but 2.4.9 is to be installed
```

I have tried reinstalling libapt 2.4.8 and could not find a .deb for 2.4.9 and the message still appears when using apt-get.
For example;

```
sudo apt-get install libapt-pkg6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libapt-pkg6.0 is already the newest version (2.4.8).
libapt-pkg6.0 set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.9) but 2.4.8 is to be installed
 apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 2.4.8) but 2.4.9 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

apt -fix--broken install and many other solutions for missing dependencies did not work either.

Any insight appreciated!

*new to ubuntu running 22.04 server LTS with gnome*

Comment: Will you share your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as well as everything under `sources.list.d`?

Comment: Looks like you have tried to install software for a different release of Ubuntu. Don't do that.

Comment: Xserver is part of Xorg; it's usual replacement is Wayland. Nvidia however is a linux kernel module for a specific hardware GPU and not the same part of the stack as Xorg/Wayland.  Your description confuses me mixing kernel modules (aka *drivers* close to your hardware) with part of the GUI stack closer to userland.  Being specific as to what you did may help, but I'd note user535733's advice  (I note  https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/apt)

Comment: if apt is not runnable, then you have somehow broken your system. To get compatible nvidia drivers installed you need to run "Software & Updates", enable "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" *for additional choices* under "Ubuntu software". Then go to "Additional drivers" and select a driver version that you have reason to believe to be suitable, based on your hardware and software/OS choices (=what you have!).